# How do I set environment variables for app engine java devappserver in IntelliJ run configuration?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I see all sorts of instructions online that claim there is an "Environment Variables" section of the Run Configuration UI for App Engine apps.  But mine looks like this:

[image: screencap of my run config dialog]

I'm using what I think is the latest version of the Google App Engine plugin and SDK.

My app has various required environment variables that need to be set when it runs.

Comment: not specific to Google AppEngine, but in the VM options add something like this: `-Dmy.var.name1=value1 -Dmy.var.name2=value2 ...`

Comment: Could you confirm if you followed the process of the official documentation for [installing the Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/quickstart-cloud-run#installing_cloud_code) and [debugging App Engine apps](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-local)?
Right now I am thinking you may be using the soon to be deprecated [Local Development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sdk-gcloud-migration). Could you confirm that?

Comment: Thanks - You pointed me at Cloud Run, which was confusing me for a bit, but it appears it uses the same plugin as for App Engine now.  Working through converting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jose V's comment, I was able to remove all vestiges of the legacy app engine development SDK, and get past this issue.